# Multi-value checkbox within content type

Tags: nodes, forms

I simply want to make a multivalue field within my venue content type (music venue)

funky, cool, dive, swank, disco etc.

I want to be able to select those when adding a venue, and then have it display everyone that was checked. I cannot figure this out!

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a new field choose FIELD as 'List (text)' and Widget as 'Check boxes/radio buttons'
2. Then in allowed values list, give your values
   eg:
   funky|funky
   cool|cool
   dive|dive
   swank|swank
   disco|disco
3. Choose Number of values to "Unlimited"
4. Then in DEFAULT VALUE, you can see all the options as check boxes, check every boxes if you want display all as selected.

Now you will get the desired output

[image]

Comment: does this work for drupal8?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think what you're describing is better suited for taxonomy functions rather than fields in a content type.

in order to display the contents of those multi-value checkboxes in a way that you want, you'll have to edit the content type template.

can you explain more about exactly where you're stuck?